# Have I been deported from Germany? Can l apply for study Visa in UK

Tags: uk, schengen, germany, schengen-visas, deportation

I was a master degree student in Germany. Due to family and health-related issues, my study and research took more time than l expected and l had to prolong my study. And parellel to this development, l also had to extend my residence permit(study purpose). However, the German immigration authorities did refuse the extension of my residence permit and l was ordered to leave. I obeyed the order, paid my flight expenses myself and left country within the given time.
I was at the end of my study when l left Germany and l completed my research practices online and currently working on my thesis. Recently l get an admission for my PhD from the US, UK and Poland.
I am fully aware of the fact that my previous deportation story from Germany might circumvent my academic plans.
Is there anyone here who have been able to get a Visa after deportation/removal?
Additionaly, l do not have any entry ban for either Germany or Schengen Zone. I do not have criminal record.
Note: l am a Turkish passport holder.

Comment: When did you leave? Before or after your original visa expired?

Comment: You followed all the rules and instructions, never overstayed. So, no issues.

Comment: Dear Mark, l am frankly grateful for your detailed reply.

Comment: Dear Sören,l did leave within the given time and did not overstay.

Comment: Anish Sheela, thanks for your comment. I hope there might not be a total red flag for my future applications...

Comment: IIRC the UK asks about deportation, denial of entry, visa refusals, and requests to leave a country. Make sure to read the question in the application carefully, you may need to disclose this situation

Answer (score 20):

> However, the German immigration authorities did refuse the extension of my residence permit and l was ordered to leave. I obeyed the order, paid my flight expenses myself and left country within the given time.

Then you have **not** been deported, since a deportation is only required if you **do not** leave withing the given timeframe.

> [§58 - Deportation (AufentG)](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_aufenthg/englisch_aufenthg.html#p1219)
> (1) Foreigners are to be deported if the obligation to leave the federal territory is enforceable, no period has been allowed for departure or such a period has expired, and *voluntary fulfilment of the obligation to leave is **not** assured* or supervision of departure appears necessary on grounds of public security and order. If one of the conditions stipulated in section 59 (1) sentence 2 becomes applicable within the period allowed for departure, the foreigner is, as a rule, to be deported before the period expires.

You can easily verify this yourself by looking for a special **deportation** stamp in your passport. The exit stamp will be placed near that stamp.

> **Allgemeine Verwaltungsvorschrift zum Aufenthaltsgesetz**
> **58.1.7** Wird die Abschiebung eines Ausländers vollzogen, soll von der Grenzbehörde im Pass oder Passersatz des Ausländers vermerkt werden:
> „Abgeschoben“, soweit generell oder im Einzelfall nichts anderes angeordnet wird.
>
> > **General administrative regulation on the Residence Act**
> > **58.1.7** If the deportation of a foreigner is carried out, the border authorities should note in the foreigner's passport or passport substitute:
> > "Deported" unless otherwise ordered in general or in individual cases.
>
> [image]

---

**Sources**:

- [§58 - Deportation (AufentG)](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_aufenthg/englisch_aufenthg.html#p1219)

---

**Other Passport stamps**:

| Schengen Area | refused entry |
| --- | --- |
| [image] --- **Reason**: C (has no valid visa or residence permit) | [image] --- **Reason**: F (has already stayed for 90 days in the preceding 180-day period on the territory of the Member States of the European Union) |

- See: [Schengen Border Code ANNEX V Part B](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=celex%3A32016R0399#d1e34-36-1) for full list of reasons

| United Kingdom refused entry | Schengen Area Exit stamp invalidated |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] (because of UK refused entry) |

See also: [usa - How to visit Paris after getting deported for intra-Schengen connection flight? - Travel Stack Exchange](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/178297/95267)

Comment: Dear Mark, my order has been based on  Section 82(4). As l already explained, my extended study caused a problem for the Visa extension. As far as l understand from this section, the lack of sufficienf progress lead to my ausweisung or ausreiseverplichtung( expulsion). When you have time may you also look at that section and share your impression with me? Do you think that is this section really a big red flag on my travel/immigration history ?I looked at the source that you put the link but since English is not my first language l could not fully comprehend it.

Comment: Your resident permit was not renewed and you left as required. With that you complied with the law. This has no negative effect on your travel history. Had you **not** complied with the law, then the procces of deportation would have been started which would eventuelly lead to being **detained** and **escorted** (at least) to the plane after a **Abgeschoben/Deported** stamp was placed in your passport. From what you wrote none of this happened, so you were **not** deported/removed.

Comment: @MarkJohnson The OP may still need to disclose the situation in their UK visa application. IIRC the questions about past immigration history are quite broad.

Comment: @Traveller When, then only that the residence permit was not renewed (as a student).

Comment: Mark Johnson: is it possible that the nonrenewal of the residence permit was accompanied by an imposition of _Ausreiseverplichtung_?  If that did happen, and if @Traveller is correct in recalling that the UK question includes requests to leave a country, then it would be necessary to disclose this incident.

Comment: @phoog That would be the case by **§59 Androhung der Abschiebung** ([§59 Deportation warning](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_aufenthg/englisch_aufenthg.html#p1248)), but is not the same as **§50 - Obligation to leave the federal territory**.