# Re-entry and exit crossed out stamps

Tags: passport-stamps, frankfurt

[image]I was recently granted Schengen visa (single entry) . After my stay, when leaving the Schengen area my flight was rebooked to the next day. So I technically had no where to go that night.
German authorities in Frankfurt granted me re-entry despite having a single entry visa (apparently they made an exception) and made two diagonal line on the corner of my exit stamp 11.07. When leaving the next day, the guard was asking me questions about my situation and asked me to show him flight itineraries . After explaining the situation he stamped me exit and made two diagonal lines on the re-entry stamp (with an annotation below it but i don’t know what does it mean)

I’m afraid this would affect my future visa applications despite that I had no control over flight delays/cancellations. I would appreciate any support or explanations!

Comment: See also: [schengen - Have I been deported from Germany? Can l apply for study Visa in UK](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/177508/95267) for other samples of Schengen passport stamp markings.

Comment: And also [Two diagonal lines in passport stamp](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/182273/32790).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> I’m afraid this would affect my future visa applications despite that I had no control over flight delays/cancellations. I would appreciate any support or explanations!

You can't take blame for something that isn't your fault.

The two diagonal lines are laid out in the [Schengen Border Guard Handbook](https://www.udiregelverk.no/contentassets/5a463696bdc244f19531815252240ec9/schengen_practical_handbook_for_border_guards_2022.10.28.pdf) 8.6 as *annulment* of the stamp

> ### Best practice: annulment of an entry or exit stamp in cases other than refusal of entry:
>
> There can be cases where a stamp that has already been affixed on a passport has to be annulled (for example, if the wrong stamp was affixed by mistake by the border guard).
> In such cases, **the traveller bears no responsibility for it** and therefore the stamp cannot be cancelled in the same ways as when a person is refused entry.

It won't have any effect on your future application, as they've effectively *cancelled* your exit and entry stamps as if you never left in the first place.

In the state your stamps are, are taken into consideration the fact that you entered on the 1st of June and left on the 12th of July, that exit on the 11th doesn't exist for all intents and purposes

---

This is in stark opposition to a black cross on the entry stamp indicating a **refusal of entry**

[image]

---

> (apparently they made an exception)

This happens regularly when you can't take a flight due to an overnight delay like that

---

> (with an annotation below it but i don’t know what does it mean)

> BPOLI FRA

[Stands for](https://www.bundespolizei.de/SharedDocs/Webs/Downloads/IFG/bras009_pdf.pdf?__blob=publicationFile&v=12)

> Bundespolizeiinspektion Flughafen Frankfurt am Main II

This is just a way to identify that the Federal Police were responsible for the annulment at the 2nd inspection station - Frankfurt airport